# How to prevent Win+L from dropping Zoom meeting

Tags: windows, zoom-meeting

Scenario: I'm in a Zoom meeting (using Windows client) and the host calls for a 15 min coffee break. I get up from my computer and hit Win+L to prevent wanted intrusions on my PC. I come back and I've inadvertantly left the Zoom meeting.

Is there a way to prevent this? A Zoom setting, perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like unintended behavior from the Zoom client.  it is more than likely not possible to prevent the behavior you describe.